# Formula - find and copy from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have sheet 1 with column a (ID numbers) and column b (contract numbers), and sheet 2 with column a (ID numbers).

I need to find the ID numbers from sheet 2 in sheet 1, and copy the relevant contract numbers in sheet 2 (in a new column).

Can you please help with the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could use the `VLOOKUP` [formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) for this. The VLOOKUP formula will look for a specified value in the left-most column of a table or range, and then returns a value from the same row of a column you specify.

For example, say you have the following on `Sheet 1`:
[image]

You would then use the `VLOOKUP` formula on `Sheet 2` to find the ID in Sheet 1 and return the correlated Contract, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "vertical lookup" function in your second sheet. Use something like the pseudocode below in the cell you want the information to appear in the second sheet .. where column 2 contains the information "looked up" in sheet one that you want.

> =vlookup(-cell reference containing ID in second sheet-,-reference to all of sheet 1-,2,false)